# Define return type when parameter is a certain value

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have two definitions that are exactly the same, however I would like it if the first one returned `Promise<Cursor<T>>` when the value of `limit` is greater than  `1`, and second one should returned `Promise<T>` if the value of `limit is 1` how would I define this, is it possible to define or is there another way to define it?

```
public async select<T extends any>(limit: number): Promise<Cursor<T>>

public async select<T extends any>(limit: number): limit is 1 && Promise<T>

public async select<T extends any>(...args: any[]): Promise<T | Cursor<T>> {
  // Do query and return the Pomise
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a numeric literal type in your overload to get the desired effect:

```
class Cursor<T>{}
class O {

    public async select<T extends any>(limit: 1): Promise<T>
    public async select<T extends any>(limit: number): Promise<Cursor<T>>


    public async select<T extends any>(...args: any[]): Promise<T | Cursor<T>> {
        return null as any

    }
}
let o = new O();
let s = o.select(1) // Promise<{}>
let m = o.select(2) // Promise<Cursor<{}>>
```

This will however only work if you pass the constant 1 to the function, and might cause more confusion then it's worth.

```
let n = 1;
o.select(n);//  n is a number so it's types as a Promise<Cursor<{}>> 
const constOne = 1;
o.select(constOne);// Promise<{}>
```

Comment: does the definition order matter? If you moved `...(limit: 1)...` above the the first one, would that one take precedence?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn order matters, but in this case the compiler will prefer the very specific overload regardless of order apparently (I changed just to be sure) but the problem I point out remains, as it is caused by the type of the passed in parameter (`n` is number, so the compiler can't possibly select the overload with 1)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn It's one of those, technically possible but better not situations in my opinion. I would go with an explicit `selectOne`  extra method.

Comment: `const n = 1` works and validates, just not `let` or `var` as you pointed out

Comment: Yes, for `const` the compiler will infer the most restrictive type possible so `const n = 1` is equivalent to `const n:1 =1`, it will not work with variables.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn But since the second overlaod can sometimes return a `Promise<T>` I would type it `public async select<T extends any>(limit: number): Promise<T| Cursor<T>>` as otherwise for `let n = 1; o.select(n)` the return type is actually wrong